# cannot find config.php in the sub-directory

Tags: php, xampp

I have a problem with config.php that need your help. I have 3 files named index1.php, caller.php and config.php. The index1.php is located in root directory and the others are located in subdir which is the sub-directory of root.

index1.php

```
<?php
require_once("subdir/caller.php");
?>
```

caller.php

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
echo "Hi from config.php";
?>
```

When I try http: //localhost/index1.php the browser shows nothing (FireFox & IE). If I change the code in caller.php to require_once("subdir/config.php") then I can see the text. In the other hand, if I change the name of config.php to something else like convit.php and update the code in caller.php to require_once("convit.php") then I also can see the text.

Can you explain to me why. I have just installed XAMPP on Windows 8 and have not configured anything in the system except fixing the security vulnerabilities.

Kind regards,
Thang

Comment: Your posted code works fine for me. Renders in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I have tried this both on Windows XP and Windows 8 and had the same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It may be a bug of XAMPP (xampp-win32-1.8.3-3-VC11-installer). I have tried with WAMPSERVER (Wampserver2.4-x64) and have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better use

`<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."config.php");
?>`

in caller.php

Comment: Thank you. Your code should be added DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR to make it work. However it will be same as require_once("subdir/config.php") that I posted above. Just remind that caller.php and config.php are located on the same directory. Why need to add a relative directory to the file path to make it work? Why I just change the file name of config.php to something else to have the expected result?